# Apache Kafka Kraft QuorumControllerEventHandler processBrokerHeartbeat: unable to start processing because of NotControllerException

Tags: apache-kafka, kraft

Kafka version 3.2.0
Running with KRaft mode

i start 3 kafka brokers. The broker kafka-2 is down for long time and keep throwing error

```
ERROR [QuorumControllerEventHandler:QuorumController@360] - [Controller 2] processBrokerHeartbeat: unable to start processing because of NotControllerException.
```

And now only 2 brokers online, 1 broker offline. I have no idea how can fix it or will it auto resolve?

Getting the log, gafana dashboard, metric and check the client are still working

Comment: have you fixed it? let me know how please